# How to convert latin1_swedish_ci collation string into hindi text

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-collation

Hi Everyone i am facing a problem with string collation change as i have millions of rows in latin1_swedish_ci collation and i wants to convert the reocords to hindi text and store in utf8_unicode_ci

$string="à¤…à¤ªà¤¨à¥‡ à¤ªà¥à¤¯à¤¾à¤° à¤¸à¥‡ à¤…à¤ªà¤¨à¥€ à¤¦à¤¿à¤² à¤•à¥€ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¤ à¤•à¤¹à¥‡à¤";

$string="à¤…à¤ªà¤¨à¥‡ à¤ªà¥à¤¯à¤¾à¤° à¤¸à¥‡ à¤…à¤ªà¤¨à¥€ à¤¦à¤¿à¤² à¤•à¥€ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¤ à¤•à¤¹à¥‡à¤";

Comment: Collation is rules set which is applied while the strings are compared. Maybe you need in CHARACTER SET convertion? if so then read about CONVERT(.. USING ..) function.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE my_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can end up with multibyte data stored in a latin1 column. The simplest case is when your client application has a utf8 connection and the data is written to the latin1 column.

If this is the case, you should be able to view the content correctly with:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(latin1_col AS BINARY) USING utf8mb4) FROM tbl;
```

If this query returns the text as desired, add a new column to your table, populate it and ***verify it***, ***before*** dropping or modifying the existing latin1 column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN new_utf8_col VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
UPDATE tbl SET new_utf8_col = CONVERT(CAST(latin1_col AS BINARY) USING utf8mb4);
```